# Finding Data Pump Dump Location in 12c

Tags: database, oracle, import, oracle12c

First and foremost, apologies for a very novice question here. I was just starting to get the hang of how the data pump dump worked in 11g when the customers I support moved to 12c. Darn the luck. :)

So a hopefully quick question: I'm using a coworker's Windows server running 12c to try to import a customer's data pump dump (have their dump and log file), but I have no idea where to place the dump for import.  When I run:

```
select * from dba_directories where directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

this is the output returned:

```
c:\ade\aime_v\oracle/admin/seeddata/dpdump/
```

That directory does not exist anywhere on this machine, plus it looks like an unusual directory path. (My coworker is on vacation, else I'd just ask of course).

So has something changed in 12c where it treats directories a bit differently?  I keep thinking surely the one who created this server couldn't have just pointed the data pump dir to a non-existent path like that. I'm presently googling myself in circles, so I suppose the short question is simply where do I begin as a first step in figuring out where my directory is for dropping my dump import file?

Again, apologies for the embarrassingly newbie question, and thanks in advance for entertaining my question.

Comment: That can't be a valid path.  Just change it to a valid directory or create another directory object.

Comment: select * from dba_directories where directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle will let you create a directory metadata entry to a non-existant physical directory which is what happened here.  So whatever user has `CREATE ANY DICTIONARY` authority would need to (re-)create the Oracle metadata directory to an existing directory, and ensure the operating system permissions on the physical directory are set up to allow the Oracle user ID to read and write to that directory.  As @OldProgrammer suggested, it looks like someone combined half Unix and half Windows path separators.

If there is a directory c:\ade\aime_v\oracle\admin\seeddata\dpdump (and your dump file is there) then the following should work; if you are importing from a non-dba ID (some_user in the sample below), you will need to have the dba grant read on that directory also:

```
drop directory data_pump_dir;
create directory data_pump_dir as 'c:\ade\aime_v\oracle\admin\seeddata\dpdump';
-- grant read on data_pump_dir to some_user;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! That's a simpler explanation than I had feared. I'll get that adjusted accordingly then.

Comment: a closing quote is missing after 'DATA_PUMP_DIR.. This is not the problem but it's a stumbling point when trying the example by cut&paste

Comment: The missing closing quote is in the original question, not my answer :)   I will edit the original question to fix it.

Answer (score 15):

Use the following sql query.

```
select * from dba_directories where directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

Comment: The original question was edited to fix a typo to reflect the correct SQL query. The OP must have had the syntax correct as it returned a result.

Comment: The value return using your query did not return the correct path on my system. The following worked for me: select * from dba_directories where directory_name='DATAPUMPDIR';